# Suppose $F_Y (y) = y^3$ for $0 ≤ y < 1/2$, and $F_Y (y) = 1 − y^3$ for $1/2 ≤ y ≤ 1$. Compute $P(1/3 < Y < 3/4)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $F_Y (y) =\begin{cases} y^3 & 0 ≤ y < 1/2\\ 1 − y^3& 1/2 ≤ y ≤ 1.\\\end{cases}$

Compute each of the following.

(a) $P(1/3 < Y < 3/4)$

---

Attempt:

$$P(1/3 < Y < 3/4) = P(Y < 3/4) - P(Y \leq 1/3) = (1-(3/4)^3)-(1/3)^3 = \frac{935}{1728}$$

Why is this wrong?

Comment: What is $F_Y$? Please declare the objects!

Comment: "Why is this wrong?" Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: $$F(Y = y)$$. The solution says otherwise. The answer they got is 29/64

Comment: You apparently assumed $F_Y$ to be a *cumulative distribution function*.  But since $F_Y(1) = 0$, this cannot be the right assumption.  Again, the error and the way of correcting it hinge on defining properly what $F_Y$ represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the formula for $F_Y$, which I assumed it was the (cumulative) distribution function of $Y$, I see that this is not a CDF by any means. It is not only undefined outside $[0,1]$ (which could be easily arranged), but it is decreasing between $y=\frac12$ and $y=1$, which is impossible. So, either it is a a probability density function (usually noted $f_Y$) and the correct answer would be
$$\int_{1/3}^{3/4} f_Y(y) dy$$
(although you should check before that 
$$\int_{0}^{1} f_Y(y) dy=1$$
to be able to assume this is a PDF) or something is wrong somewhere.

---

UPDATE: I've checked the numbers and it turns out that
$$\int_{0}^{1} f_Y(y) dy=\frac9{32},$$
so this isn't a PDF either (nevertheless, $\frac{32}9 F_Y$ would).